# CMake to Bazel Migration

Tags: ubuntu, bazel

I'm converting CMake project to Bazel.

I have top-level `CMakeLists.txt` which uses some global variables like `TYPE_A`, `TYPE_B`. There is another `CMakeLists.txt` which uses the above variables.

Following is the folder structure

[image]

Content of `CMakeLists.txt` inside "app" folder contains the following content.

```
option(TYPE_A "A BUILD" ON)
option(TYPE_B "B BUILD" ON)
```

Content of `CMakeLists.txt` inside "app2" folder contains the following content.

```
if (${TYPE_A})
//Do someprocesing
endif()


if(${TYPE_B})
//Do someprocessing
endif()
```

My question is how will I set the options which are present in CMakeLists.txt(inside "app" folder) in Bazel and access the same variables in the BUILD file inside the "app2" folder. In other words how will i bazelize "app" and "app2" packages?

Comment: show some [MCVE] in your question, please!

Comment: updated the question. I did go thru the following page https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/tutorial-sharing-variables.html But quite not able to get it.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why not hard code the behavior in app2 for example? If you don't want to hard code it, you can use config_setting pair with --define on the command line (or set by default in a .bazelrc).

Comment: @SebastianÄrleryd: I'm trying to bazelize cmake project. Actually in this example, i have showed only two packages, but in reality there are 5 packages. So hard coding it in 5 packages doesn't seem appropriate. Can you give some more inputs on "config_setting pair". I'm a newbie to bazel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [rules_foreign_cc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc) to keep building that part of the source tree with CMake.